# how to change animation direction in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my widget , i want to find the part that is responsible of the direction of rotation to control if it is right to left or left to right

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isLeaving = (index - pageNotifier) <= 0;
    final t = (index - pageNotifier);
    final rotationY = lerpDouble(0, 90, t);
    final opacity = lerpDouble(0, 1, t.abs())!.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    final transform = Matrix4.identity();
    transform.setEntry(3, 2, 0.001);
    transform.rotateY(-degToRad(rotationY!).toDouble());
    return Transform(
      alignment: isLeaving ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      transform: transform,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          child,
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: opacity,
              child: SizedBox.shrink(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Check this video, both sides are doing the same animation because both are going to the next index :

https://youtu.be/92XftcJveYU

Comment: it is determine by the value of `rotationY` variable

Comment: Any idea on how to make it do the same animation but at the opposite direction

Comment: add a minus sign before `rotationY`?

Comment: nop , it didn't work :(

Comment: no change at all?

Comment: it changed the animation instead of rotating as a cube changed into sliding from page to another

Comment: sorry I have no idea what cube and sliding you mean

Comment: @pskink I've added a very short video for it .. it will be crystal clear after you watch it  ,,thank you ^_^

Comment: your `final t` can be < 0 which doesn't work with `lerpDouble` - check https://gist.github.com/pskink/c04de9b3d643b14051a6bca5189985c1 for example